# Emgu.CV.Util.CvException: 'OpenCV: i < 0' Exception

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am new on EmguCV. I'm trying to '*DrawContours*' using the `CvInvoke.DrawContours()` method, but, when running I have the following exception:

> Emgu.CV.Util.CvException: 'OpenCV: i < 0'

The error code is

```
if (biggestCountor.Size != 0)
{
     CvInvoke.DrawContours(imgBiggestContours, biggestCountor, -1, new MCvScalar(0, 255, 100), 20);
}
```

The `biggestCountor` variable is a `VectorOfPoint` type and it's value is

> [234, 110]
>
> [174, 369]
>
> [601, 405]

which represents the `Points` coordinates.

I believe the error is with the `biggestCountor` variable, because, when replacing it for another variable of the same type, but with different values on this same code, it works.

I am using the *EmguCV 4.5.1.4349* with *Visual Studio 2019*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that if you are trying to draw into an image that has a fourth channel (alpha channel) you can get this type of exception. I always try to check the type of image first to see if it only has more than 3 channels and if it does I convert it using RGBA to RGB, then you can call the drawContours